# Node-red dynamic RBE for multiple sensors

Tags: workflow, node-red

I want to write data into DB only if it has changed. For that i've used Swith + RBE nodes ().

[image]

What i would like to achieve is to have dynamic number of sensors. Switch is separating by mac address of sensor. Payload into node "by sensor" looks like that:

`msg.payload = {"tmp":22.8,"hum":36,"batt":73,"mac":"a4c1382665a7"}`

So my goal is to write data into database if it is has changed. How could I make marked area 'dynamic' so i could easily add new sensors without changing node-red workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RBE runs separate channels for each `msg.topic` so as long as each sensor uses a different topic then they should be filtered accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Its mentioned in the documentation, and I've missed it..